# 'Duplicate entries for key' error when creating an Istio IngrressGateway on EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, istio

I'm trying to create an Istio ingress gateway (istio: 1.9.1, EKS: 1.18) with a duplicate `targetPort` like this:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: istio
spec:
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: ingressgateway
        k8s:
          service:
            ports:
              - port: 80
                targetPort: 8080
                name: http2
              - port: 443
                name: https
                targetPort: 8080
```

but I get the error:

```
- Processing resources for Ingress gateways.
✘ Ingress gateways encountered an error: failed to update resource with server-side apply for obj Deployment/istio-system/istio: failed to create typed patch object: errors:
.spec.template.spec.containers[name="istio-proxy"].ports: duplicate entries for key [containerPort=8080,protocol="TCP"]
```

I am running Istio in EKS so we terminate TLS at the NLB, so all traffic (`http` and `https`) should go to the pod on the same port (8080)

Any ideas how I can solve this issue?

Comment: If you are terminating TLS on NLB, what's the need to have two ports? Just redirect on the load balancer from port 80 to 443, then have the certificates checked, forward it to the instances, and have just one port listening. The error makes sense, by the way. It is trying to configure the same port of the Envoy proxy (as ingressgateway is just one Envoy proxy), so it throws an error.

Comment: Hi Suren, unfortunately you cant do an SSL redirect with an NLB according to AWS

Comment: You are using deprecated version of Kubernetes. Did you check it on newest (supported) version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to use different targetPorts in the end to get this working

Answer (score 1):

Until the istio 1.8 version, this type of configuration worked (although with initial problems) - [github #53526](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53526).

As of version 1.9 an error is generated and you can no longer use two of the same ports in one definition. There have also been created (or reopened) reports on github:

- [github #35349](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/35349)
- [github #53576](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/53576)
- [github #1622](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1622)

However, the issue is with an outdated version of Kubernetes and Istio at the time of writing the response.

Possible workarounds:

- Use different `targetPort`
- Upgrade Kubernetes and Istio to newest versions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that these values are used to configure both service and container definitions.

A possible solution is to override the `targetPort` port via Overlay.

```yaml
overlays:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Service
    name: my-service
    patches:
      - path: .spec.ports[name:https].targetPort
        value: 8080

service:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http2
      targetPort: 8080
    - port: 443
      name: https
      targetPort: 443 # Will be overridden with 8080
```

This will override only the service port.